# Convert TensorFlow Model to ONNX within Python using tf2onnx

Tags: python, tensorflow, onnx

Is it possible to install `tf2onnx`, e.g. using `conda` to convert TF models programmatically in Python. Such as:

```py
from tf2onnx import convert
convert(model_dir)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.
You can do a pip install also and to convert your model in ONNX format please refer to the following example: https://github.com/onnx/tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/TensorflowToOnnx-1.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
  import tf2onnx
  import onnx
  input_signature = (tf.TensorSpec((None, IMG_SIZE_H, IMG_SIZE_W, NUM_CHANNELS), tf.float32, name="image_input"),)
  onnx_model, _ = tf2onnx.convert.from_keras(model,input_signature)
  onnx.save(onnx_model, "model.onnx")
```

Not sure why you need the input_signature defined if the tf2onnx command-line is able to decode it from the saved model.